# how to get the information that did when thread is paused

Tags: delphi

how can i get actions ,i did when my thread is paused after resumed (Sorry for my bad english )
ok i will explain with code

```
function mythreadf(p:Pointer):DWORD stdcall;

var   i:Integer;

begin  

  for i:=0 to 1000000 do    begin

     if myevent.WaitFor(INFINITE)=wrsignaled
then

     begin

       if Form1.RadioButton1.Checked then ShowMessage('Checked');

       Form1.Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(i);

     end; 
   end;

end;
```

i am pausing and resuming my thread using resetevent and setevent 
after i paused my thread by clicking resetevent button and then i checked radiobotton1 after that when resume my thread by using setevent again .dont send error occuring and applications closing :(

can any one help me in this issue

regards
Edit 1: 
Error image 
http://i49.tinypic.com/11r7nkn.jpg

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, "when resume my thread by using setevent again .dont send error occuring and applications closing."  When you invoke SetEvent, some sort of error occurs that causes the application to close (crash?) unexpectedly.  Does it give an error dialog?  What does the message say?  If you posted details about the error it would help quite a bit.

Comment: error image added see main post sir

Comment: That doesn't help much.  Try running it under the debugger and see if it gives you any exception dialogs.  Those will contain useful information.

Comment: Better name for this question: "how do I learn to write multi-threaded code in Delphi that is safe, reliable, and stable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing VCL UI controls directly in a worker thread is NOT thread-safe (even ShowMessage() is not thread-safe.  Use the Win32 API MessageBox() directly instead). All kinds of bad things can happen, including crashes.  You must delegate your UI access to the main thread instead.  The TThread class has a Synchronize() method for that purpose.  Or you can use any other inter-thread synchronization of your choosing, such as by using SendMessage() to send custom messages to a hidden window created in the main thread via AllocateHWnd() or CreateWindow/Ex().

Answer (score 0):

Your thread, as Remy says, should not be accessing the checkbox. Also it's bad programming style.  Your background thread has a purpose?  That purpose will help you find a name.  If you create a class that inherits from TThread, you will get farther, faster.

```
interface
 type
   TMyElephantCountingThread = class(TThread)
        protected
            FResultStr:String; // holds something for later display on the user interface
            FOptionChecked:Boolean; // set from main thread, to tell background thread whether or not a checkbox option is checked.
  ....
 end;
....
implementation
 ....
function TMyElephantCountingThread.ElephantCounterResults;
begin  
  // all data fields in here is local to this thread 
   if FOptionChecked then 
          FResultStr := IntToStr(FIntegerValue);

end;
```

As you can see my code above uses only fields that belong to my thread object.

If FOptionChecked needs to be set equal to the value of Checkbox.checked, that must be done in the main thread.

You can not copy and paste write  code from your foreground thread (which can access your VCL objects) into your background thread code (which can not safely access those objects), and not expect problems.